# Print error messages for multiple select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to print out error messages from a multiple select in Laravel:

```
@if($errors->has('interests')
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach($errors->get('interests') as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

Furthermore, my select has a property with `name="interests[]"`. What do I do wrong?

Comment: post the error what you are getting

Comment: I'm not getting anything. That's the issue. The if-statement does not show any errors.

Comment: I suppose you are using laravel validation validation and you have return redirect()->withErrors()?

Comment: I do. The errors exist in the messagebag of $errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this kind of validation

```
'interests' => 'required|array|...'
```

and not target specific validation then, there will only be 1 error message for that field. So you can do this

```
@if($errors->has('interests'))
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
        <li>{{ $errors->first('interests') }}</li>
    </ul>
@endif
```